# Do a function based on a value in a variabel Google Apps script calendar/spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My script collects data from a Google Form. And puts it into a Spreadsheet. Based on the info in the spreadsheet it should add Calendar events. When the user chose 1 of 2 countrys in the form i would like the script to execute the function for that country.

Norway is one value
Sweden is one value

For example if the value in  `var country2 = country1.getValue();` is "Sweden" i would like it to only execute the `function sweButik(){`  Is it possible, and how do i do it?

```
function getData() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();    
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);

  var time1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);
  var name1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4);
  var info1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
  var country1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6);

  var time2 = time1.getValue();
  var name2 = name1.getValue();
  var info2 = info1.getValue();
  var country2 = country1.getValue();

}

//////////////////////////  

  function sweButik(){ 

var sweButik1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_7gvpuutc6h1d7kk5mjb2s5f4ds@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name2, 
     new Date(time2),
new Date(time2),    {description: info2});                                                                                                                                


  var sweButik2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_bertj0lfja45425ran8mmrpgc8@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name2, 
     new Date(time2),
new Date(time2),    {description: info2});                                                                                                                                

}

/////////////////////////

    function norButik(){

var norButik1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_7d88i0ne013r26i172k8fu16j0@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name2, 
     new Date(tid2),
new Date(tid2),    {description: info2});                                                                                                                                


  var norButik2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_sb0ddqmj5ql6uu5769u0qfs2go@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name2, 
     new Date(time2),
new Date(time2),    {description: info2});                                                                                                                                


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your values are fixed, you can do something like :

```
var country2 = country1.getValue();

if (country2 == "Sweden") {
    sweButik();
} else if (country2 == "Norway") {
    norButik();
}
```

But you need some parameters to be passed to these functions, so sweButik will become :

```
function sweButik (name,time,info) {
    var sweButik1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_7gvpuutc6h1d7kk5mjb2s5f4ds@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name, 
     new Date(time),
new Date(time),    {description: info});                                                                                                                                


  var sweButik2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.com_bertj0lfja45425ran8mmrpgc8@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(name, 
     new Date(time),
new Date(time),    {description: info});
}
```

And its call will be :

```
sweButik(name2, time2, info2);
```

Don't forget to do the same for `norButik`

Comment: @JohnSmith Pleased to help you :)